# pyspark modify class attributes using spark.sql.rdd.foreach()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The main task is to connect Hive and read data using spark rdd.

I have tried the code below. Connection and reading are both successful, but when I want to modify the value of `self.jobUserProfile`, I failed. Then I print this value in three positions(masking in #1,#2 and #3). In the first position, the value is valid, but in the second and third position, the dict is empty. It seems that the modification has not been assigned into the class attribute.

I have tried `response = spark.sql('select userid, logtime from hive.dwd_log_login_i_d limit 10').collect()` and iterate this dataframe, but when the data volume is too large, the performance may decline.

When I change `response.rdd.foreach(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x))` to `response.rdd.map(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x))`, the target value in three position are all empty.

I'm a newbie in spark. Any advice could be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
from analysis.common.db.hive.connectHive import *
import collections

class OperateHive():
    def __init__(self):
        self.jobUserProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    def readLoginFunction(self, e):
        dic = collections.defaultdict()
        dic['userid'] = e[0]
        dic['logtime'] = e[1]
        self.jobUserProfile[e[0]] = dic
        print(self.jobUserProfile)  #1

    def readLogin(self, spark):
        response = spark.sql('select userid, logtime from hive.dwd_log_login_i_d limit 10')
        response.rdd.foreach(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x))
        print(self.jobUserProfile)  #2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = connectHive(['conf/hdfs-site.xml', 'conf/hive-site.xml'], 'utf-8')
    operateHive = OperateHive()
    operateHive.readLogin(spark)
    print(operateHive.jobUserProfile) #3
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code below works.

```
from analysis.common.db.hive.connectHive import *
import collections

class OperateHive():
    def readLoginFunction(self, e,jobUserProfile, devAppProfile):
        dic = collections.defaultdict()
        dic['userid'] = e[0]
        dic['logtime'] = e[1]
        jobUserProfile[e[0]] = dic
        devAppProfile[e[0]] = dic
        print(jobUserProfile)
        return jobUserProfile, devAppProfile

    def readLogin(self, spark, jobUserProfile,devAppProfile):
        response = spark.sql('select userid, logtime from hive.dwd_log_login_i_d limit 10')
        rdd1 = response.rdd.map(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile))
        return rdd1.top(1)[0][0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = connectHive(['conf/hdfs-site.xml', 'conf/hive-site.xml'], 'utf-8')
    jobUserProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    devAppProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    operateHive = OperateHive()
    jobUserProfile = operateHive.readLogin(spark, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile)
    print(jobUserProfile)
```

But when I remove `devAppProfile`, the code show like below:

```
from analysis.common.db.hive.connectHive import *
import collections

class OperateHive():
    def readLoginFunction(self, e,jobUserProfile, devAppProfile):
        dic = collections.defaultdict()
        dic['userid'] = e[0]
        dic['logtime'] = e[1]
        jobUserProfile[e[0]] = dic
        devAppProfile[e[0]] = dic
        print(jobUserProfile)
        return jobUserProfile

    def readLogin(self, spark, jobUserProfile,devAppProfile):
        response = spark.sql('select userid, logtime from hive.dwd_log_login_i_d limit 10')
        response.rdd.map(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = connectHive(['conf/hdfs-site.xml', 'conf/hive-site.xml'], 'utf-8')
    jobUserProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    devAppProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    operateHive = OperateHive()
    operateHive.readLogin(spark, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile)
```

The `rdd.map()` won't work as there is no print in `print(jobUserProfile)`.

Then I change the code like below, which works again.

```
from analysis.common.db.hive.connectHive import *
import collections

class OperateHive():
    def readLoginFunction(self, e,jobUserProfile, devAppProfile):
        dic = collections.defaultdict()
        dic['userid'] = e[0]
        dic['logtime'] = e[1]
        jobUserProfile[e[0]] = dic
        devAppProfile[e[0]] = dic
        print(jobUserProfile)
        return jobUserProfile

    def readLogin(self, spark, jobUserProfile,devAppProfile):
        response = spark.sql('select userid, logtime from hive.dwd_log_login_i_d limit 10')
        rdd1 = response.rdd.map(lambda x: self.readLoginFunction(x, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile))
        return rdd1.collect()[-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = connectHive(['conf/hdfs-site.xml', 'conf/hive-site.xml'], 'utf-8')
    jobUserProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    devAppProfile = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    operateHive = OperateHive()
    jobUserProfile = operateHive.readLogin(spark, jobUserProfile, devAppProfile)
    print(jobUserProfile)
```

The problem on the post is about closure. But I don't work out why the three versions on the answer work differently.